# DotNetNuke Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, dotnetnuke

```
DotNetNuke Configuration Error
Could not find a part of the path `'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\community.realeflow.com\Config\Backup_20131224939\web_.config'.Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\community.realeflow.com\web.config' is denied.`
```

I've tried multiple things to fix this error so can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the installation process of DNN carefully and make sure you setup the Permissions on the website folder carefully.

Depending on your configuration of the website/application pool in IIS, you will need to configure MODIFY permissions on the folder for the Account that the application pool is using in IIS.